# Switching from focus page to confirmation page using webdriver

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to enter into the following web page in Python (https://power.larc.nasa.gov/data-access-viewer/). A confirmation page (let's say "Welcome to the power data access viewer!") appears simultaneously with the main page (let's say "Power Data Access Viewer"). I used the following code to close the confirmation page (by clicking on "Access Data" button), but I could not succeed. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://power.larc.nasa.gov/data-access-viewer/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mysplash']/div[2]/div[2]").click()
```

Unfortunately, I received the error below. I have to add that two pages (main and confirmation pages) belong to two separate classes in one web-page, while I think there is a same class in case of "Alert&Popup". Thus, the "Switch-To" function did not work too. Furthermore, I applied "driver.window_handles" to get two pages address, but I received identical address.

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*    [@id='mysplash']/div[2]/div[2]"}

Again, thanks your help in advance.

[Illustration figure of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGuBe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wait, the `confirmation page` appears after a few moments and you can locate the element by `css selector`:

```
driver.get("https://power.larc.nasa.gov/data-access-viewer/")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.enable-btn')))
element.click()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```